# Remove empty column from access form

Tags: ms-access

So I'm new to access and making some modifications to some existing forms. I had to delete some columns from forms that are no longer used, which I did by removing them from the select query. I am however left with line delimiters for the columns that no longer exist, as you can see here.

[image: empty columns]

edit: This is a subform. The form layout is to enter a project and type, and depending on what you enter it will display several different tabs, and the pictured table is displayed under one of the tabs.

Comment: Remove the controls (textboxes) that were bound to the removed fields.

Comment: It looks like there is only 1 control for the entire table https://imgur.com/a/8V3wRid

Comment: Could be the table has been embedded as a subform. The simplest might be to recreate the form.

Comment: It is a subform, sorry for not mentioning that (again, am new with access). Also sorry I didn't provide more complete screen shots but gotta be careful about revealing identifying or proprietary info. I'll remake it then, though I'm curious so I can lookout for it, where would it have been defined as to how many columns there were and what width they were? I did have to rename Ratings as well and I noticed the width didn't change so it's a bit squeezed.

Comment: It looks like the (empty) subform control is at runtime set to a form via code. You need to find that form and edit it.

Comment: Well, a sub form would not be a problem but your screen shot shows a listbox, and they ARE MOST certainly sensitive to the column count. So, are you talking about a sub form or a listbox. Your sceen shot shows a listbox. You have to check the column count, and set the list box column count to match, or re-run the wizard to re-create the listbox based on the new query.